# Pandas: Difference to previous value

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas Data Frame that looks like this

```
GROUP   VALUE    MASK
  1        5     false
  2       10     false
  2       20     false
  1        7     true
  3        17    false
  3        18    false
  1        100   false
  1        200   true
```

For every row where the MASK is true I would like to get the difference to the previous value within this group, i.e., the result should be

```
VALUE DIFF
  7      2
  200  100
```

How can I compute this in Pandas?

How can I compute this fast for a large data frame with about 2 million rows and 1 million groups?

Comment: in response to speed comment below:  Make sure you are using a newer version of pandas as there have been great improvements in the speed of groupby with large numbers of groups.  Aside from that, you might think about subsetting your data if you'll be doing repeated calcs on the same subset.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the bottleneck is `groupby`. You don't actually need to use `groupby` for this specific problem. To `sort` the dataframe by `GROUP`, perform `diff` on the sorted dataframe and `filter` by `MASK` should be okay. We must use `kind='mergesort'` to keep the order unchanged within the group before and after sorting,

Assume MASK is always False for the first element of each group ( since the first element is meaningless for difference operation ), you can use this

```
pd.concat([df.VALUE, df.sort_values(by="GROUP", kind='mergesort').VALUE.diff()], axis=1, keys=['VALUE', 'DIFF'])[df.MASK]
```

Performance Tests:

```
MAXN = 200000
GROUPS = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({"GROUP": np.ceil(np.random.rand(MAXN)*GROUPS), "VALUE": np.ceil(np.random.rand(MAXN)*10000), "MASK":np.floor(np.random.rand(MAXN)*2).astype("bool")})

%timeit t1 = pd.concat([df.VALUE, df.groupby('GROUP').VALUE.diff()], axis=1, keys=['VALUE', 'DIFF'])[df.MASK]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.28 s per loop

%timeit t2 = pd.concat([df.VALUE, df.sort_values(by="GROUP", kind='mergesort').VALUE.diff()], axis=1, keys=['VALUE', 'DIFF'])[df.MASK]
#10 loops, best of 3: 63.1 ms per loop

#MAXN = 2000000
#GROUPS = 1000000
%timeit t2 = pd.concat([df.VALUE, df.sort_values(by="GROUP", kind='mergesort').VALUE.diff()], axis=1, keys=['VALUE', 'DIFF'])[df.MASK]
#1 loop, best of 3: 1.24 s per loop
```

Comment: That takes more than 10s so I didn't wait for the result :P.

Comment: Fair enough, I see you were just showing the timing for the # of rows and groups as specified in the question.  Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

use `groupby`, `diff`, `'MASK'`

```
pd.concat([df.VALUE, df.groupby('GROUP').VALUE.diff()],
          axis=1, keys=['VALUE', 'DIFF'])[df.MASK]
```

[image]

Comment: The step `df.groupby('GROUP').VALUE.diff()` seems to be really slow. Is there a way to speed it up?